# single positional indexer is out-of-bounds : Error

Tags: python, pandas

I am practicing working in dataframe in pandas.i came across an error for which i dont understand the reason why there is an error.Can some one explain me the reason.
Note:
This only occurs when i use **df.iloc[i+1,0]** line of code. if i only use  **df.iloc[i,0]** it works fine

Dataframe:

```
A,B
1,2
2,3
4,5
5,6
6,7
7,8
9,10
```

Code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("text.txt")
for i in range(0,len(df)):
    if (df.iloc[i,0] + df.iloc[i+1,0]) == 5 :
        print("hey")
```

Error: **single positional indexer is out-of-bounds**

Comment: If you have three buckets and you ask what is in the fourth bucket, the single position indexer (ie the number determining what bucket you want to look at) is out of bounds (ie how many buckets you have). This happens because of `df.iloc[i+1, 0]` when `i == len(df) - 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Your program finds the current value and the next value in the column "A". However, once it reaches the end of the "A" column of the dataframe, there are no other values in the dataframe, but it still looks for the next value: `.iloc[i + 1, 0]`, which doesn't exist. This leads to the error you were having. The issue can be solved by changing the range to 1 less than the length of the dataframe. That means the loop will stop one value before the end of the dataframe, read the final value, then exit.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("test.txt")
for i in range(0,len(df)-1):
    if (df.iloc[i,0] + df.iloc[i+1,0]) == 5 :
        print("hey")
```

Answer (score 0):

If `i` reaches the maximal possible value in

```
for i in range(0, len(df))
```

then `i+1` will be out of this range.